# What are possible reasons for bonfire Assets::add_module_css to not include file?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, bonfire

I have a primary controller located in `secure/application/modules/gps/controllers` that has a constructor that looks like this:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('gps_model');
        Assets::add_module_js('gps', 'gps.js');
        Assets::add_module_css('gps','gps.css');
        if($this->input->get('clear') != false){
         $this->session->sess_destroy();
        }
    }
```

My CSS file that I am trying to include is located in the folder `secure/application/modules/gps/assets/css`.  The code executes fine without warning, but the CSS file does not get included for any methods.  Is there a configuration setting the may override the assets directory, or is there some other reason it's not being found/added?  (The JS file is not being added either.  The bonfire base CSS files (screen.css) IS getting loaded fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution to our particular problem.

The assets/cache directory did not exist.  Once the server could write (it must exist and be writeable!) to the `[document_root]/bonfire/public/assets/cache` directory all was good.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but I have faced the same problem and found help with the below information.

It'll added in your page but can you just look on ctrl+u source where bonfire will auto rename your file.

**For example :** In my code I have added id_proof_master.css file like below.

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->restrict($this->permissionView);
        $this->load->model('id_proof_master/id_proof_master_model');
        $this->lang->load('id_proof_master');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<span class='error'>", "</span>");

        Template::set_block('sub_nav', 'master/_sub_nav');

        Assets::add_module_js('id_proof_master', 'id_proof_master.js');
        Assets::add_module_css('id_proof_master', 'id_proof_master.css');
    }
```

And it's working fine but when I have check in source view (ctrl+u) it will show file name like **"id_proof_master_master_mod.min.css"** so can you just check it out in source; maybe it'll show you with some other name like my file.